# how to test if Long ends with a number pattern on JAVA?

Tags: java, numbers

Given 2 longs on JAVA, num and pattern, how to test if num ends with pattern?

For exemple:

num = 7838123
pattern = 123

Must be return true, because num ends with 123 (the pattern).

num = 7838123
pattern = 120

Must be return false, because num not ends with 120 (the pattern).

I've already transformed the long to string and use the endsWidth method, but, is it possible to use another quick strategy like bitwise operations?

Comment: You really ddn't think of any usable strategy?

Comment: You could always convert it to a string and use a regular expression.

Comment: @applecrusher why a regex? endsWith() is all you need.

Comment: Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). From that second link: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Comment: @JBNizet  Good point. I forgot about that method.

Comment: Start by wondering how you would determine if 7838123 ends with 3. Wonder how you would get the final 3 out of 7838123 and out of 123. Then wonder how you would get 783812 out of 7838123, and 12 out of 123. Repeat the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i agree with @shmosel solution. But it's true just when second number has only 3 digits.

```
boolean compareTail(long one, long two) {
    int digits =(int) Math.log10(two)+1;
    long formated = one % ((long) Math.pow(10, digits));
    return formated == two;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the pattern is always 3 digits, you can use a simple mod:

```
boolean matches = (num % 1000 == pattern);
```

Comment: The pattern can be any number of digits